# how to export data from hive table using beeline cli

Tags: hive, beeline

I am unable to extract data from hive table to file using beeline interface. The thing that worked with hive interface is not working onbeeline. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code what you are trying .

Comment: beeline -u jdbc:hive2://<database server> --silent=true --outputformat=csv2 -f hive.hql > data.txt

Comment: Try this beeline -u db_url -n user_name -p password -f hive.hql > data.txt      it should work.Let me know if its still giving error

Comment: Unable to connect the jdbc url using beeline -u, but when I am using !connect I am able to make a connection. but from inside beeline I am unable to export the data to file

Answer (score 0):

Did u create metastore in mysql db. While creating metastore in mysql u should give metastore userid and password. Also most the important thing is u have to give metastore username and password properties in hive-site.xml

[https://itsnirmal.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/hive-mysql-metastore-and-hiveserver2-setup/](http://itsnirmal.wordpress.com/2016/08/31/hive-mysql-metastore-and-hiveserver2-setup/)